# solve integral equation using the theory of compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

Find solutions of
$$u(x)-\lambda\int^{2\pi}_0\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j}cos(jy)cos(jx)u(y)dy=sin^2x$$
for all values of $\lambda$. Find the resolvent kernel for this equation. (Find the least squares solution if necessary.)

I have to solve it using the methods of compact operator. I searched for few days, but I can't seem to get a good resource on how to use this method. Any help on solving this problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is set up to use Fourier series. First,
$$
       \cos(2x) = \cos^{2}(x)-\sin^{2}(x)=1-2\sin^{2}(x) \\
          \sin^{2}(x) = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}.
$$
So, for $n \ge 2$, it is consistent to assume
$$
                   u(x) = A + B\cos(2x).
$$
Assuming $n \ge 2$,
$$
             A + B\cos(2x) - \lambda B \frac{1}{2}\pi\cos(2x) = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) \\
            A = \frac{1}{2},\;\; B(1-\lambda\pi/2) = -\frac{1}{2} \\
                A=\frac{1}{2},\;\; B = \frac{1}{\lambda\pi-2}
$$
The solution is
$$
                 u(x) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\lambda\pi-2}\cos(2x).
$$
That should get you started.

Comment: Why did we assume $u(x)=A+Bcos(2x)$?

Comment: @user3382078 : The functions $1,\cos x,\cos 2x,\cdots$ are orthogonal. The only ones appearing on the right are $1,\cos 2x$.